# Laravel Routes and 'Class@Method' notation - how to pass parameters in URL to method

Tags: laravel, routes

I am new to Laravel so am uncertain of the notation.  The Laravel documentation shows you can pass a parameter this way:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Which is very intuitive.  Here is some existing coding in a project I'm undertaking, found in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('geolocate', 'Api\CountriesController@geolocate');
# which of course will call geolocate() in that class
```

And here is the code I want to pass a variable to:

```
Route::get('feed/{identifier}', 'Api\FeedController@feed');
```

The question being, how do I pass `$identifier` to the class as:

```
feed($identifier)
```

Thanks!

Also one further sequitir question from this, how would I notate {identifier} so that it is optional, i.e. simply `/feed/` would match this route?

Comment: <a href="feed/58"></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a link which looks like:

```
/feed/123
```

Then, in your controller the method would look like this:

```
feed($identifier)
{
    // Do something with $identifier
}
```

Laravel is smart enough to map router parameters to controller method arguments, which is nice!

Alternatively, you could use the `Request` object to return the `identifier` value like this:

```
feed()
{
    Request::get('identifier');
}
```

Both methods have their merits, I'd personally use the first example for grabbing one or two router parameters and the second example for when I need to do more complicated things.

Comment: So basically, Laravel figures that, by declaring `{identifier}`, I want it as a variable and makes it available.  I'm liking Laravel more and more :)  Is there a good link for documentation on any 3rd parameters that can be used in the `Route::get()` call?

Comment: Yup, and you have as many route parameters are you like really! (Having lots of them is hard work though...) The Laravel docs are great - the request object is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/requests. I've used the facade in my example, but there are other ways of accessing it which are documented there.